# How I create a PairRDD?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to create a `PairRDD` (draft_ids) where the `key` is the identifier of the project and the `value` is all the fields obtained with the `split` method. We have the `rdd` draft

```
draft.take(3).foreach(println)

[Ljava.lang.String;@302bf7bb
[Ljava.lang.String;@3128929f
[Ljava.lang.String;@30037ad7
```

Comment: Unfortunately, *we* don't have the RDD `draft`. Please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: can you share sample csv content..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a mapToPair function, which returns a Tuple
For example in python:

```
def myMap2pair(element):
    key = element.getKey()
    value = element.getValue()
    return key, value

draftKV = draft.map(myMap2pair)
```

Comment: you can use a lambda as well ;)